# Mechanize python nested form error

Tags: python, forms, mechanize

I am trying to fill up a form that has following fields :
old password , new password , verify password

```
<b><u>Please Enter the Informations</u></b><br>
<form method=post action="chpass.php?action=changepass">
<table border=0>
<tr><td>LAN UserName</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Old password</td><td><input type="password" name="password"></td></tr>
<tr><td>New password</td><td><input type="password" name="password1"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Conform password</td><td><input type="password" name="password2"></td></tr>
tr><td colspan=2 align=center>
<input type=submit name="submit" value="submit">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<form><input type="button" onClick="show();" value="Logout"></form>
```

Using following piece of code in python:

```
br.open('url_of_form')
br.select_form(nr=0)
br['password']='abc'
br['password1']='bcdef'
br['password2']='bcdef'
br.submit()
```

I have used this piece of code before to login to site but this isn't working while trying to change password . The error message says 'ParseError: nested FORMs' .

what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two open tags and one close tag "form". Maybe its a problem? Try to use [grab](http://grablib.org/)

Comment: Edit:  this is actual form :

<form method=post action="chpass.php?action=changepass">
<table border=0>
<tr><td>LAN UserName</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Old password</td><td><input type="password" name="password"></td></tr>
<tr><td>New password</td><td><input type="password" name="password1"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Conform password</td><td><input type="password" name="password2"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2 align=center><input type=submit name="submit" value="submit">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<form><input type="button" onClick="show();" value="Logout"></form>
</td></tr></table>
</form>

Comment: do we have documentation page in english ,btw ?

Comment: We havent. See examples and source.